# Git ignores MeteorJS directories /lib and /server

Tags: git, github, meteor, gitignore, directory-structure

I'm developing an app using MeteorJS, and when uploading to GitHub, the directories /lib and /server are ignored. Any ideas why? Here are the contents of my .gitignore file that was automatically generated by MeteorJS:

`local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted git (purposely) does not track empty directories (well, directories really).  Here is a (quite lengthy but interesting) read on this topic if you are interest: [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) .  It includes an interesting link to an article by Linus T himself as to why this shouldn't happen.

BTW -- I hope that .gitignore file was in your .meteor directory?  The purpose is to not pollute your git repo with the local MongoDB storage that meteor creates and uses by default.  That can get large!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that Git ignores empty directories, that's why they were not showing up.